# Can someone help me to make my question more focused?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, moderation

My [question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/160435/54017) has been closed because it is considered not focused.
I'd like to know if, for old Gmail accounts,  there could be the possibility of name conflicts and I provide some sources and factual circumstances supporting this hypothesis.

Could you tell me, what is unclear (or unfocused) and what can I do to make it more focused?

Answer (score 1):

The question is the reopening queue. Please be patient.

In the meantime it's worthy to say that the referred post was closed because it was making two questions:

1. Email delivery to Gmail email addresses
2. Google account login

While it is now focused on the first question it still is not clear why the similar questions doesn't answer it here are some examples:

- [Change my Gmail sender address from firstname.lastname to firstnamelastname](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/17975/88163)
- [Why does Google not consider dot in usernames of Gmail addresses?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/14668/88163)
- [Why does Gmail force a dot in my email address?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/119777/88163)

Please review those and other related posts and if you still need help, edit your question to include a brief explanation about why the most relevant answers doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Hi Rubin. My question addresses a slightly different problem. While we know for sure that, in these days, first.last is the same as firstlast (and this is addressed from your linked questions), some sources claim that (at some point) _in the past_ this behaviour was not enforced. Whether this is true is the subject of my question.

Comment: That looks to be off-topic in this site. Please edit your questions and explain how is that relevant nowadays for using Gmail.

Comment: This is simply because thousands of people might be affected today, if they got their Gmail address long time ago.